# Return value of Linked List?

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
Ticket tk2 = new Ticket();
Flight ff2 = new Flight();
Flight tmp = new Flight();

System.out.print("Enter ticket ID to cancel: ");
tk2.id = Integer.parseInt(sc2.nextLine());
System.out.print("Enter Flight ID of this ticket: ");
ff2.id = Integer.parseInt(sc2.nextLine());

if (listFlight.check(ff2)) {         
    tmp = listFlight.get(ff2);
    //tmp.tickets.delete(tk2);
    //System.out.println("Deleted");
```

and here listFlight class and get function:

```
public T get(T el){
    SLLNode<T> tmp;
    for (tmp = head; tmp != null && tmp.info.equals(el); tmp = tmp.next);
    return (T)tmp;
}
```

It show error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: fullversion.SLLNode cannot be cast to fullversion.Flight
>       at fullversion.FullVersion.main(FullVersion.java:90)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    Flight s = (Flight)obj;
    return this.id == s.id;
}
```

I don't know why I can't use `tmp = listFlight.get(ff2)`. Can someone explain?

`SLLNode`:

```
public class SLLNode<T> {
    public T info;
    public SLLNode<T> next;

    public SLLNode(){
        this(null, null);
    }

    public SLLNode(T el){
        this(el, null);
    }

    public SLLNode(T el, SLLNode<T> ptr){
        info = el;
        next = ptr;
    }
}
```

`Flight` class:

```
public class Flight {
    int id;
    String flightHour;
    TicketList tickets = new TicketList();

    public Flight(){
        this.id = 0;
        this.flightHour = "";
        this.tickets = null;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        Flight s = (Flight)obj;
        return this.id == s.id;
    }
}
```

`listFlight` class:

```
public class Flights extends SLL<Flight>{

    public void reserve(Flight f){
        if(check(f) == false)
            this.addToTail(f);
    }

    public void cancel(Flight f){
        this.delete(f);
    }

    public boolean check(Flight f){
        return this.isInList(f);
    }

    public void display(){
        if(!isEmpty())
            this.printAll();
    }   
}
```

`SLL` class:

```
public class SLL<T> {
    protected SLLNode<T> head, tail;

    public SLL(){
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return head == null;
    }


    public boolean isInList(T el){
        SLLNode<T> tmp;
        for(tmp = head; tmp != null && !tmp.info.equals(el); tmp = tmp.next);
        return tmp != null;
    }


    public T get(T el){
        SLLNode<T> tmp;
        for(tmp = head; tmp != null && tmp.info.equals(el); tmp = tmp.next);

        return (T)tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see the definition of `listFlight` in your code.

Comment: listFlight class:
http://notepad.cc/xoggajo56
SLL class: http://notepad.cc/xaslaucu47

Comment: `tmp` is an `SLLNode<T>`. Doesn't `SLLNode` have a method to retrieve it's payload, `T`?

Comment: @TrungThành Please edit your question to add this information in the main body.

Comment: Could you add the code for `SLLNode`?

Comment: I use Linked list, like Linked list in Linked list

I mean, I have Flights( list flight) have many flight. Each flight have ticketList, ticketList have many ticket. Now I know ticket ID and I want to find what flight have that ticket and remove it. That just i try to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the `info` member of `SLLNode` should fix the exception:

```
public T get(T el){
    SLLNode<T> tmp;
    for(tmp = head; tmp != null && tmp.info.equals(el); tmp = tmp.next);

    return tmp.info;  // Changed line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `equals` function is not consistent with `equals` contract: it should never throw an `Exception`, but you throw an Exception in case of `obj` not being `Flight`, you should firstly check if `obj` is `Flight`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (!(obj instanceof Flight)) return false;
    // or even
    // obj.getClass().equals(Flight.class)
    // if you want exactly this class and not its descendants

    Flight s = (Flight)obj;
    return this.id == s.id;
}
```

So, your error looks like you've passed something, that is not `Flight` to `Flight.equals`.

Comment: i thnk equal function working well.
value of 
    listFlight.get(ff2) is a Flight
and tmp also Flight
but i cant use tmp = listFlight.get(ff2)

Comment: @TrungThành Obviously, it's `fullversion.SLLNode`